# Google web fonts diacritics display from other font

Tags: html, css, meta-tags

I used the Archivo Narrow font from the Google web fonts but the diacritics display from the body font which is Lucida Grande. So everything but the romanian diacritics (that i need) are shown in the Archivo Narrow font. And is not a problem of missing glyphs.

I have this in the `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Narrow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and in css i call the font like this:
`font-family:'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif; !important;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `href` attribute value in the `link` element to

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Narrow&subset=latin,latin-ext
```

as instructed in the Google instructions when you check the “Latin Extended (latin-ext)” checkbox. The exact meaning of this checkbox is undocumented, but apparently you should use this option whenever you have Latin letters beyond the Latin 1 (“Western”) repertoire